# SVG how to scale an arrow to the parent tag?

Tags: html, svg

Here is the target the SVG that I want to scale to the parent and maintain its aspect ratio.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g transform=""translate(11.26,0.75) rotate(90)"">      
        <path d="M5.76 6.58 L5.76 9.2 L3.14 9.2 L3.14 10.51 L0 7.9 L3.14 5.27 L3.14 6.58 L5.76 6.58 Z" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

If I wrap it in a DIV and that container has a height 100, then the width should scale with it and vis versa.  When I try to do it, it keeps moving its XY coordinates and I don't know why.  I've read this https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/ and followed the examples, but still nothing.

I don't know why the arrow dances around when I try to set the viewBox.  Can someone shed some light and explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the viewBox attribute on the svg element:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 5 6 6">
```

The browser needs to know what part of the SVG it needs to draw before it can scale it.

Comment: This answer helped me find the root cause.  After you provided a small enough viewBox, it clicked of how the viewBox worked.  For those with similar issues.  The viewBox represents the part of the SVG, like a window of where the image is located in the SVG.  So once you capture those dimensions, then you can apply scaling on top of it to achieve your desired result.